# Entity Framework View Generation Fails

Tags: entity-framework, view

I'm trying to pre-generate views for an EF model. I followed the instructions at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx) but I keep getting an error from EdmGen:

Method not found:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.String>
>   System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.GetViews(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
>   ByRef)'.

The command line I'm using is:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" /nologo /language:CSharp /mode:ViewGeneration "/inssdl:$(TargetDir)BarInventory.ssdl" "/incsdl:$(TargetDir)BarInventory.csdl" "/inmsl:$(TargetDir)BarInventory.msl" "/outviews:$(ProjectDir)BarInventory.Views.cs"
```

I've set the "Metadata Artifact Processing" property on my model to "Copy to Output Directory".

Also, I'm using VS 2010 and this is the first time I've done this. I'm also using the EF June 2011 CTP.

Thanks.

Comment: Switch back to .NET 4 and try it again.

Comment: Just tried .NET 4. As soon as I change the target, I get an element namespace error about an EnumType (which I'm using in my model). EdmGen won't run at all. I have another project that I didn't use enums in. I'll try it there.

Comment: I get the same error in a project I had before the June CTP was intalled. It's targeted for .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.